# Ruby on Rails: inserting a partial in different language (locale)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, view, erb, partials

There is a view which is calling a partial in my multilingual application:

```
  <%= render :partial => 'shared/order', :object => @order %>
```

the default language is Russian and **shared/_order.html.erb** uses I18n.t

```
<%= t('.order_type') %>: <b><%= t("order_types.#{order.order_type}") %></b>
<%= t '.date_and_time' %>: <b><%= l(order.date, :format => :long) %>
```

And I want to render just the same partial one more time but in English without changing the **I18n.locale** variable. By writing something like this:

```
  <%= render :partial => 'shared/order', :object => @order %>
  <%= render :partial => 'shared/order', :object => @order, :locale => 'en' %>
```

What is the best practices to achieve such behaviour?

Answer (score 7):

You can always use something like this to run a code block in a certain locale:

```
<%= render :partial => 'shared/order', :object => @order %>
<%- I18n.with_locale('en') do %>
  <%= render :partial => 'shared/order', :object => @order %>
<%- end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmmm. Difficult question. I would do the following:

```
<%= render :partial => 'shared/order', :object => @order %>
<%= render :partial => 'shared/order', :object => @order, :locals => {:locale => 'en'} %>
```

and then in the partial view:

```
<% before_locale = I18n.locale %>
<% locale ||= before_locale %>
<% I18n.locale = locale %>

..... do things here ....

<% # return back to original locale %>
<% I18n.locale = before_locale %>
```

I really do not know whether this is the best. Just crossed my mind as first solution to your problem.

Comment: Yep. This was mine first solution too. Thanx anyway!

Comment: Hi, I preferred using specific locale on each translation. `<%= t "bidibip", locale: locale %>`